# SQL Merge statement with indexed view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2016 and am trying to create a `MERGE` statement that will insert a new record if it doesn't exist or grab the id of the record if it does exists.

This is working properly, but is having the unintended side affect of causing an indexed view to be updated, even though there is no data being updated when I run this multiple times.

Is this expected behavior or am I just doing something wrong?

Intuitively I guess I would expect that because the merge finds a match, then only updates a local variable, no changes to the indexed view would show up at all in the execution plan.

[image: Execution Plan]

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer
(
    CustomerId INT IDENTITY(100,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    CustomerName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.Customer_v
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT CustomerId, CustomerName 
    FROM dbo.Customer
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [CL_IX_Customer_v]
ON dbo.Customer_v(CustomerId ASC);
GO

DECLARE @CustomerId AS INT
DECLARE @CustomerName AS VARCHAR(100) = 'Mike Smith'
DECLARE @WasCustomerCreated AS BIT = 0
DECLARE @SummaryOfChanges TABLE(Change VARCHAR(20));

MERGE INTO dbo.Customer AS Target
USING (VALUES (@CustomerName)) AS Source (CustomerName) ON (Target.CustomerName = Source.CustomerName)

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET @CustomerId = Target.CustomerId

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (CustomerName) VALUES (@CustomerName)

OUTPUT $action INTO @SummaryOfChanges;

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @SummaryOfChanges WHERE Change = 'Insert')
BEGIN
    SET @WasCustomerCreated = 1
    SET @CustomerId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END

SELECT @CustomerId AS CustomerId, @WasCustomerCreated AS WasCustomerCreated
```

Comment: Interestingly, if you take out the `WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE` part altogether you still get the same query plan showing that the indexed view is being updated

Answer (score 0):

You can add "AND @CustomerId <> Target.CustomerId" to the merge statement:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.Customer AS Target
USING (VALUES(@CustomerName)) AS Source (CustomerName)
ON (Target.CustomerName = Source.CustomerName)
WHEN MATCHED AND @CustomerId <> Target.CustomerId THEN UPDATE SET @CustomerId = Target.CustomerId
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (CustomerName) VALUES (@CustomerName)
OUTPUT $action INTO @SummaryOfChanges;
```

Comment: @CustomerId in this case is acting like an OUT parameter, so it's always NULL to start with, so I don't think that actually helps at all.  Plus adding that still produces the same query plan showing that clustered index is getting updated when I think it shouldn't be